# Using command line to split files

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, command

This is what I'm currently using to split my files:

```
split -l 500 myfile.txt file_
```

and it automatically creates file like file_aa, file_ab, and so on.

Is there a way to use numbers instead of letter so that it's file_1, file_2, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man split says:

```
split -d -n 4 -l 500 myfile.txt file_
```

or

```
split --numeric-suffixes --digits=4 --lines=500 myfile.txt file_
```

Comment: As soon as it hits 99 files it says "split: output file suffixes exhausted"